# using channels with google pubsub poll subscriber

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create a google pubsub subscriber in golang where I take 100 messages at at a time and then write them to influx. I'm trying to use channels to do this like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "encoding/json"
    clnt "github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2"
    "time"
)

type SensorData struct {
    Pressure      float64 `json:"pressure"`
    Temperature   float64 `json:"temperature"`
    Dewpoint      float64 `json:"dewpoint"`
    Timecollected int64   `json:"timecollected"`
    Latitude      float64 `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude     float64 `json:"longitude"`
    Humidity      float64 `json:"humidity"`
    SensorID      string  `json:"sensorId"`
    Zipcode       int     `json:"zipcode"`
    Warehouse     string  `json:"warehouse"`
    Area          string  `json:"area"`
}

type SensorPoints struct {
    SensorData      []SensorData
}

func main () {

    messages := make(chan SensorData, 100)

    // Create a new Influx HTTPClient
    c, err := clnt.NewHTTPClient(clnt.HTTPConfig{
        Addr:     "http://localhost:8086",
        Username: "user",
        Password: "pass",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    // Create pubsub subscriber
    ctx := context.Background()
    proj := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")
    if proj == "" {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable must be set.\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, proj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not create pubsub Client: %v", err)
    }
    const sub = "influxwriter"


    //create influx a blank batchpoint set
    bp, err := clnt.NewBatchPoints(clnt.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  "sensordata",
        Precision: "s",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }



    // Pull messages via the subscription.
    go pullMsgs(client, sub, messages)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    writeInflux(messages, bp)

    c.Close()

}


func pullMsgs(client *pubsub.Client, name string, messages chan<- SensorData) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // [START pubsub_subscriber_async_pull]
    // [START pubsub_quickstart_subscriber]
    // Consume 10 messages.

    var mu sync.Mutex
    var sensorinfos SensorPoints
    sensorinfo := &SensorData{}

    received := 0
    sub := client.Subscription(name)
    cctx, _ := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    err := sub.Receive(cctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        msg.Ack()

        json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, sensorinfo)

        //fmt.Println(string(msg.Data))
        //fmt.Println(sensorinfo.SensorID)

        sensorinfos.SensorData = append(sensorinfos.SensorData, *sensorinfo)

        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        received++
        fmt.Println("rcv: ", received)
        messages <- *sensorinfo

    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // [END pubsub_subscriber_async_pull]
    // [END pubsub_quickstart_subscriber]
}

func writeInflux(sensorpoints <- chan SensorData, bp clnt.BatchPoints) {

    for p := range sensorpoints {

        // Create a point and add to batch
        tags := map[string]string{
            "sensorId": p.SensorID,
            "warehouse": p.Warehouse,
            "area": p.Area,
            "zipcode": string(p.Zipcode),
        }

        fields := map[string]interface{}{
            "pressure":   p.Pressure,
            "humidity": p.Humidity,
            "temperature":   p.Temperature,
            "dewpoint":   p.Dewpoint,
            "longitude":   p.Longitude,
            "latitude":   p.Latitude,
        }

        pt, err := clnt.NewPoint("sensordata", tags, fields, time.Unix(p.Timecollected, 0))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        bp.AddPoint(pt)


    }


}
```

but it doesn't see to every get past the initial `pullMsgs` function and just keeps printing the output in there:

```
rcv:  1
rcv:  2
rcv:  3
rcv:  4
rcv:  5
rcv:  6
rcv:  7
```

I thought that once the channel get full, it should block until the channel is emptied out

this is the pubsub pull code I'm using as a reference.

Comment: Re: "I thought that once the channel get full, it should block until the channel is emptied out"...  almost.  Once a channel is full a send operation will block until the channel is not full -- doesn't have to be empty.  So what are you seeing, `rcv: 100` and it gets stuck?  Does the program exit?  Have you put a print statement as the first line in the `writeInflux` function and confirmed it never gets called?  Btw it doesn't look like `err` is updated before being checked after the `pullMsgs` call.

Comment: @jrefior, naw, the program doesn't exit...it keeps going as the the message count keeps going up `rcv: n`...looking at the google docs a bit more (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull), it looks like the subscriber itself is non-block but i'm not sure how to really handle that then?

Answer (score 1):

When you've sent the desired number of messages on the channel, close the channel and cancel the context.  Try using the technique demonstrated in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) of canceling after some number of messages.  Since your buffer is 100 and you're trying to consume 100 messages at a time, that's the number.  If you want your program to exit, close the channel so that the `for e := range ch` loop in `writeInflux` hits a stopping point and doesn't block waiting for more elements to be added to the channel.

Note this in [the Go pubsub API doc](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub):

> To terminate a call to Receive, cancel its context.

That is not what's stalling your main goroutine, but your `pullMsgs` goroutine will not exit on its own without that cancel.

Also, check for errors on `Unmarshal`.  If you don't want to handle unmarshal errors at this point in the code, consider changing the channel type and sending `msg` or `msg.Data` instead and unmarshaling upon channel receipt.

```
cctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
err := sub.Receive(cctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
    msg.Ack()
    err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, sensorinfo)
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Printf("Failed to unmarshal: %s\n", err)
    }
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    received++
    fmt.Println("rcv: ", received)
    messages <- *sensorinfo
    if received == 100 {
        close(messages)  // no more messages will be sent on channel
        cancel()
    }
```

Comment: so what do I do if I just want to program just run for ever as messages get put into pubsub..I tried to remove `cancel()` but got this then: `panic: send on closed channel`

Comment: I tried to recreate the channel like this too: ` for {

  var messages = make(chan SensorData, 100)

  // Pull messages via the subscription.
  pullMsgs(client, sub, messages)
  if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
  }

  writeInflux(messages, bp)
 }` but that doesn't seem to work either...how do I keep this running?